Why is Desktop folder empty?
In Ubuntu 24.04: looking in the Home folder there is a folder called Desktop, but it contains nothing. Yet there are apps on my Ubuntu desktop. I had hoped by adding a file herein it would appear as a desktop app, but no dice. Where should it go?
(that is: ~/Desktop/arduino-ide_2.3.3_Linux_64bit.AppImage )
